# Impact on FCC certification due to replacement of GPS receiver module

Tags: fcc, certification, compliance

1. Can anyone please guide on whether the replacement of GPS receiver with the same spec from the another brand for the cost reduction would impact the FCC approval received for the device or not? If yes then the product will need to be tested thoroughly or some specific testing would be necessary?
2. Will the replacement of small components like capacitor, resistor, etc. affect the FCC approval of the device even though the components are going to be replaced with the components of the same specs from another brand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’re changing a major component- yes you will have to retest. As for simple components, you need to ensure that they perform similarly to the ones used in the test device. UL may not approve of any substitution unless you have submitted change documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For FCC it comes down to whether you can make a compelling engineering argument that there should be no change in system behaviour, and whether you are willing to take the financial/reputational risk.

For discrete components with no significant difference (such as chip resistors) there should be no issue.  Replacing one type of cap with another of equal value, but different behaviour (say very different ESR), in an area which might impact emissions, you are on thinner ice.  Changing a complex subassembly with a functionally equivalent alternative, but totally different implementation, is hard to justify.

The really critical thing to consider are the consequences if the change actually causes the device to fail certification.

If you have shipped hundreds of thousands of units, and have to undertake a recall due to a breach which causes significant user issues, you may have made a very expensive mistake.

In personal experience, like-for-like component changes (and even minor schematic changes) are generally done without retest, whereas more major changes require at least a basic check to verify you've not introduced significant issues.

In your specific situation, case 2 is probably fine without retest, but case 1 is suspect.  The main get out would be if the two GPS modules use the same chipset with the same recommended schematic.  In that case you might well be fine, especially if the modules have been successfully certified in other apps.

However, it is up to you to assess the cost savings of not testing vs the exposure...